# How to tell the difference between when app is launched with a notification verses merely brought to the foreground with a notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

When my app is not running and a user taps on the notification in the notification center, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function is called with push data passed into the `launchOptions` dictionary.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //do stuff with push data in launchOptions dictionary

}
```

but also the `userNotificationCenter` `didRecieve` function is called

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    log.info()
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    print(state)
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState != .active {
        log.debug("exiting because app is not in active state")
        return
    }
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    //do stuff with userInfo
    completionHandler()
}
```

In `didRecieve` function, how can i tell that the app was launched versus the app was already running in the background when the user tapped on the notification?

The `application` is **active** when the app is in the foreground but it is **inactive** when the app is in the background or was launched from the push, so i can't tell the difference.

The `application didRecieveRemoteNotification` looks ideal but it is only called when i send a silent push but my pushes aren't silent.

Comment: In didRecieve method you need to find out whether the application was previously in background or inActive state? if so, why do you need this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to try using `willPresent` function for handle your push in foreground case? Something like this

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    handlePushWhenForeground(notification?.request.content.userInfo) // implement this function
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {
        handlePushWhenBackground(response.notification.request.content.userInfo) // implement this function
    } else {
        handlePushWhenNotActivated(response.notification.request.content.userInfo) // implement this function
    }
}
```